# Google Sheets: Commas Disappearing with Regexreplace

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with 20+ users adding info. The sheet contains a column for "URL" but the URL with the word "visit/" must be in hypertext markdown in order for the links to be clickable on the internal dashboard. The issue is that the commas are disappearing. Thanks in advance.

| URL | Formula | Result I want |
| --- | --- | --- |
| visit/settings, visit/profile | [visit/settings](http://visit/settings) [visit/profile](http://visit/profile) | [visit/settings](http://visit/settings), [visit/profile](http://visit/profile) |

[Example Google Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ERLvmZJad-_Li8vjQAIaidQjj9uR_pa0eOZydTNpV6M/edit#gid=0)

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(Σ,", "&char(10)))),lambda(Λ,regexreplace(Λ,"^visit/.*","[$0](http://$0)")))))))
```

Comment: the new line break in Input_Cell A2 is changed to single space in expected output_C2 but similar scenario in A5; the new line stays as is in expected output_C5. any specific logic to this?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, Whoops! Good catch. I fixed Cell C2 so that it would mimic Cell A2. If possible, I am trying to have Column C mimic Column A. Since Cell A2 has line break then C2 should have line break. Since Cell A4 is separated by comma, then C4 is also separated by comma. However if that is not possible then single line should work for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,regexreplace(Σ,"visit/[\w-]+","[$0](http://$0)"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Thank you!